# What does an Air Battle Manager do?

Tags: military, us-air-force

I heard someone talking about a position in the U.S. Air Force called an Air Battle Manager or ABM. What does a person in this position do?

Comment: Do we have a military SE?  This really seems like it should be there if there is one...

Comment: Wikipedia has a [1,400-word article on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_battle_manager). Did you read it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Air battle manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_battle_manager) has the following duties:

- Plan and execute theater air operations
- Analyze national defense strategy
- Develop and conduct flying and simulation exercises
- Conduct, manage, evaluate and improve unit training and readiness
- Create operational policies

Further information can be found at [AirForce's website](http://www.airforce.com/careers/detail/air-battle-manager-abm/).

In USAirForce, there are seven categories of aeronautical ratings. They are:

- Pilot
- Navigator
- Combat Systems Officer (CSO)
- Air Battle Manager (ABM)
- RPA Pilot
- Observer
- Flight Surgeon

For further reading about these ratings, read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Air_Force_aeronautical_rating).

Comment: Isn't this the type of thing a typical officer does? Is an Air Battle Manager different from the typical USAF officer in any way?

Comment: @flyingfisch I added some more details. Are you asking about difference in responsibilities between ABM and a pilot?

Comment: Ah, thanks, those details helped :)